# How to improve this proof about real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

I've trying to prove the following: let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \geq 0$ if for every real $\epsilon > 0$ we have $0 \leq a < \epsilon$ then $a =0$.

I'm *sure* that there is a proof much simpler the one I gave using infimum and supremum, however, I couldn't find it. I've proved it like this:

Consider the intervals $[0,\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, we want to show that the only $a$ in all of them is the zero number. In other words we want to prove that the intersection of all of them is just $0$. To do this we are going to show that the complement is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. We consider the complement:

$$\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcap_{\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+}[0,\epsilon)=\bigcup_{\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+}(-\infty,0)\cup [\epsilon,+\infty)=(-\infty,0)\cup \bigcup_{\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+}[\epsilon,+\infty)$$

Now since the union is over *every* positive $\epsilon$ that union is of course the entire set of positive reals $(0,+\infty)$, so that the complement is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty) = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and so the only element in the intersection is $0$ and hence $ a =0$.

Now is this proof good or there is a better one using $\sup$ and $\inf$? In that case, I just want a little hint on how to start with it.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Suppose $a\ne0$. Let $\epsilon=a/2$. Then....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Proof by contradiction** if $a\neq 0$ then $a>0$ so with $\epsilon =a$ we have $\epsilon\leq a$ which's a contradiction so $a=0$.

Comment: The contradiction would be better visible if you had written $\epsilon<a$ rather than $\epsilon\leq a$.

Comment: The negation of $a<\epsilon$ is $\epsilon\leq a$.

Comment: Oh, so it is more than a simple typo? I thought you were using the hypothesis stated in the question for the special case $\epsilon=a$ (allowed since $a>0$), which would have given you $a<a$ (or $\epsilon<a$ which is the same) and a contradiction. Now you suggest one should instead be using the _negation_ of the hypothesis to arrive at $\epsilon\leq a$ and a non-contradiction. I'm lost. But with so many upvotes, there must be something right with your reasoning.

Comment: OK, so I now see what I missed. After putting $\epsilon=a$ (which allows applying the hypothesis, but that's for later) you _first_ deduce directly form $\epsilon=a$ the weaker $\epsilon\leq a$ which _then_ contradicts $0\leq a<\epsilon$ (obtained from silently applying the hypothesis as just announced). Still I wonder what is the point in explicitly mentioning the weaker $\epsilon\leq a$, does it in any way "better contradict" $a<\epsilon$ then $\epsilon=a$ all by itself would have? In fact I would state the contradiction as $a<\epsilon=a$, which is clear enough.

Comment: I agree with your last sentence and  I have the habit  to look for the negation in the case I reason by contradiction.

Comment: Proof by contradiction makes sense to me!